# How Noisy is the Time Capsule (2013)?

Tags: hardware, time-capsule

I have an older Time Capsule and it's pretty noisy. Does anyone have one of the newer tall models? How loud is it in a quiet room?

Answer (score 2):

I have the newest 3TB since a few days and for me it is basically without any substantial noice.